# flutter : run provider function to load data before/while widget is loading the layout

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

*Structure of code:*
I have a function, that on a Button click returns a stateful widget `A`.
In a separate file, I have a `ChangeNotifier` class `B`, which `A`
needs (it needs the decoded json file) and I use the `ChangeNotifier` class as a general memory container which all the different widgets have access to.

```
B:
class Database_Controller extends ChangeNotifier {
  Future<void> _readVeryLargeJsonFrame() async {
    final String response =
    await rootBundle.loadString('assets/tables/largejson.json');
    final data = await json.decode(response);
    return data;
  }
  Other functions to give back entries of data
}
```

*Problem:*
I would like to execute `_readVeryLargeJsonFrame` as soon as `A` is called (potentially with a loading spinner for the user) and before `A` is loaded (or at least in parallel).

1. How do I call the ChangeNotifier function in the "init" part of a stateful widget? *Peter Koltai* mentioned the [initState method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html). But how do I call the ChangeNotifier function from this?

(2. Context problem: So far, I would be using `Provider.of<Database_Controller>(context,listen: false)._readVeryLargeJsonFrame();` but how do I get the context argument here?)

(3. Is the `Future<void> ... async`  nature of the `_readVeryLargeJsonFrame`  function a problem here?)

Comment: Do you try to call this function from `initState` method?

Comment: But how do I call the provider function in this initState ? It needs the context, right?

Comment: You have `context` available in `initState` method, check it. But otherwise I don't suggest calling an async function in `initState`, the first build will be executed before this completes. IMO a `FutureBuilder` would be better, you can easily add the progress indicator as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => yourFunction(context));
  }
```